# increasing the size of dual booted ubuntu /dev/sdb5 from the windows /dev/sda4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

My GParted disk map looks like following:

/dev/sdb: Ubuntu
[image: /dev/sdb: Ubuntu]

/dev/sda : Windows
[image: /dev/sda : Windows]

Low disk space warning on ubuntu
[image: Low disk space warning on ubuntu]

I want to increase the size of Ubuntu so the low disk space warning doesn't come. I have /dev/sda4 completely empty (199 GB); I want to bring this space to /dev/sdb5 where my ubuntu is installed. Can anyone tell me proper steps to do this. I do not want to reinstall anything; Or do not want to use and USB boot drive or anything; just want to use commands or tools to get this done. Would be really thankful.

Answer (score 0):

The two disks `sda` and `sdb` are entirely distinct and separate,
and you cannot extend one disk with space that is part of another disk.

The most you can do is format `sda4` in a compatible format (example `ext4`),
and move data over from Ubuntu. This will create more free space in the Ubuntu partition
to avoid the warning message (if you move enough).

Comment: I will have to mount the sda4 before it can be available in ubuntu for accessing every time I do a restart of system. Right ?

Comment: You can set it to be auto-mounted. One reference of many: [How To Automount File Systems on Linux](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-automount-file-systems-on-linux).

Comment: There's LVM. He can e.g. create PV/VG/LV with sda4 first, use e.g. rsync to copy everything to the LV, set the root for booting to the LV, then sdb5 can be wiped and used as a PV to extend the LV (or create another LV or even VG).

Comment: @TomYan: This approach might be worth more than a comment.